# What is the best way to get a Meta Element's Attribute Value in JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Something like this:

`this.token = document.getElementById("token").getAttribute("content");`

Even better, get the meta element `by Name`

Comment: this isn't specific to aurelia, and is a basic html question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.querySelector('meta[name="name"]').getAttribute("content");
```